# Accessing static field avoided by referencing Class?

Tags: java, static, class-reference

I'm not understanding why this is working, please help educate me.

```
Config CFIG = new Config();
Tile selectedTile = CFIG.tileGallery.get(1);
System.out.println("This is the name:" + selectedTile.getName());
Feature selectedFeature = CFIG.featureGallery.get(3);
System.out.println("This is the name:" + selectedFeature.getName()+ 
    " " + selectedFeature.getEffect(0));
```

I initialize the object `CFIG`, which sets both the member variables of the Class `Config` `tileGallery` ArrayList and `featureGallery` ArrayList.  When I run the code, it works, outputting the selected test values.  However for both of the declarative statements Netbeans gives a warning of "Accessing static field "

Using the hint of "Replace with class reference", it changes the statements to:

```
Tile selectedTile = Config.tileGallery.get(1);
Feature selectedFeature = Config.featureGallery.get(3);
```

When I run it, it still works!

Question, Config. isn't identifying which Config object to call data from.  Now I only have a single Config Object in existence, but even if I initialize a second Config object it still doesn't appear confused.

What's going on here?

EDIT: andih wondered what the code of the Config Class.  I didn't add it, because it wasn't much, and figured you could easily assume what it did as it pertains to the issue.  However, here it is, just in case.

```
public class Config {
    public static ArrayList<Tile> tileGallery;
    public static ArrayList<Feature> featureGallery;

    public Config (){
        this.tileGallery = Tile.ReadTileXML();
        this.featureGallery = Feature.ReadFeatureXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: A static variable is shared between all instances of that class. If `tileGallery` should be bound to a specific instance of the `Config` class make the `static` access specifier.

Comment: Bonus question, after changing all of the statements to use Config rather than CFIG, a new "warning" is displayed that just says "Introduce..."  Alt+Enter doesn't offer any additional information.

Again, thanks to those who offered answers, I learned something from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the exact code of your `Config` class it's hard to say but it looks like your `Config` class uses static fields like

```
   public class Config {
      public Config() { 
         titleGallery = new ArrayList();
         titleTallery.add(new Title());
      }

      public static List<Title> titleGalery;
    }
```

That's what the hint says.

In this case all your `Config` instances share the same titleGalery and you can access them via `Config.titleGalery`.

If you want different `Config`instances with different value you'll have to remove the `static` keyword to get independent instance fields.

```
public class Config {
      public Config() { 
         titleGallery = new ArrayList();
         titleGallery.add(new Title());
      }

      // old: public static List<Title> titleGalery;
      public List<Title> titleGalery;
    }
```

Comment: Doh!  I thought it meant something different. =)

Answer (score 3):

The static keyword means this field belongs to the class than instance of the class. Even if you create hundred objects , this field will be shared amoung them.
These static fields "tileGallery" and "featureGallery" from each instance will be pointing to same object in memory.

The static variable gets memory only once in class area at the time of class loading.